# Backing up Windows Server 2008 R2 to FTP server

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, windows-server-2008-r2, backup-restoration

I'm looking for an inexpensive way of backing up my Windows 2008 R2 dedicated server to an FTP server.

To be any useful, the software should also be able to restore the server by using a bootable CD and the backup set stored on the FTP server. So Windows server backup seems to be out of the question.

Can anyone recommend any suitable products? Preferably some you have actually tried yourself?

Thanks,

Adrian

**Edit:** Just to clarify, by inexpensive I mean something that costs 250 EUR or less...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used windows server backup combined with the [Super Flexible File Synchronizer](http://www.superflexible.de/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Acronis Backup & Recovery 10 is able to store backups on a ftp server. The only thing you've to test before is creating the bootable acronis media to test if your network card is supported. There is a free trial of the product so this should not be the problem.

I use the program to backup Windows Server 2003 and SmallBusinessServer 2003 to network drives over SMB.

The Datasheet http://de1.download.acronis.com/sl/YNS8PqMiOIgTAGnUDL8(9BmXSZfQVVK4rON513XT)uY/p/pdf/BackupRecoveryServerWindows_datasheet.en.pdf

Comment: That's the first software I also thought of and I'm sure it does a good job, but it certainly is not within my budget...

Comment: @adrian - "inexpensive" means many different things to different people. If you have a price range, tell us what it is in your question.

Answer (score 0):

why did you rule out R2's backups? It has disaster level restore from the windows setup disk and can restore the complete image from local USB device or over the network from bare metal. It's called "[Windows Complete PC Restore](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2009/02/04/windows-server-backup-2008-restore-from-network-location.aspx)" and its FREE. The FTP requirement sounds like a batch file to move files around.

I didn't see how HardBackup supported the FTP nor does it even list 2008 as supported. You'll have to update this thread to let us know how it works out for you.